# Zend Unable to locate form

Tags: php, class, zend-framework

I have a small (very small) zend project that covers two modules, the admin and the front module. I have also managed to create a form under the 'front' module and was also able to use it in the controllers of the front module as well. Now, my problem is that when I created a form under the 'admin' module, and use it in the admin controllers as well, the php cannot anymore detect where to locate the class. Thus, this error is displayed:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Form_Login' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\zend\finder\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php on line 18
```

I was so confused that in the front module, it is working but on the admin module, very similar way of creation and usage, it fails. NOTE: I used zf tool to create the forms.

Here is my application.ini, maybe this might help.

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.modules[] =

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

resources.view.helperPath.Finder_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Finder/View/Helper"
```

I am using Zend 1.11.12 for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't have a module bootstrap class, as everything else looks fine. So all you need to do is create a file at `application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php` which contains the following:

```
<?php

class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

this will be run by your application bootstrap, and `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap` by default sets up an instance of the module resource autoloader, which will in turn enable resources classes beginning with `Admin_`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding a form to a Library then you want it in library/admin/form/login.php (alter the case of the path accordingly) - not in the module '/modules/Admin/Controllers etc' folder. I am not sure if this is a relevant point but i made it anyway...

Then you make sure you load your module using the autoLoadNamespaces in your application.ini and the Admin folder should be in your library folder.

Comment: No. I do not place my forms under the library folder because I find it senseless of course than putting it under each modules.

Comment: ah okay - as far as i am aware (please correct me internet) Zend will look for the Admin_Form_Login in /library/admin/form/login.php by default - it looks for Controllers in your /modules/admin folder. There is probably a way round this if you prefer not to do it this way - i will have a look online because i don't know how off the top of my head! :)

Comment: yes.. by default, it will look under the library directory.. thanks MazB.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the namespace for those forms ?  In my module's Bootstrap.php (/application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php), I use the following code:

```
    //Loads the autoloader resources

    $moduleName = 'admin';
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH ."/modules/".$moduleName."/",
            'namespace' => '',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                    //Tells the application where to find the forms
                    'form' => array(
                            'path' => 'forms/',
                            'namespace' => ucfirst($moduleName).'_Form_'
                    ),
                    //Tells the application where to find the models
                    'model' => array(
                            'path' => 'models/',
                            'namespace' => ucfirst($moduleName).'_Model_'
                    )
            ),
    ));
```

Comment: There is no need to do this, as long as you have a bootstrap file in the `modules/admin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

from what i see you didn't add the Admin namespace to the autoloader.
If you are using the Autloader and the Form is under include_dir/Admin/Form/Login.php, try

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Admin_"
```

in your config.

[More Info about the Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)